# MySQL Memory Issue

Tags: mysql

I'm using MySQL version 5.5 and set max_allowed_packet in my.cnf 32M. Even though MySQL getting down periodically because of memory issue.I'm getting error like  Packet for query is too large (5667 > 1024). You can change this value on the server by setting the max_allowed_packet variable.I also tried no use.Get me solution

Comment: Did you set the same packet size also for the mysql client? By default it's 16M.

Comment: No.Only server we setting Packet size is 32M.

Comment: Then try to increase the packet size on the client:
shell> mysql --max_allowed_packet=32M

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/packet-too-large.html

Answer (score 0):

reboot your mysql server and execute this query

```
show variables like 'max_allowed_packet'
```

Comment: after rebooting MySQL sever and executing this query showing 1024 only.How can i set

Comment: This is my my.cnf configuration
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
[mysqld_safe]
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice            = 0
[mysqld]
user            = mysql

skip-external-locking
key_buffer              = 32M
max_allowed_packet      = 32M
thread_stack            = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
query_cache_limit       = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M

expire_logs_days        = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M

Comment: seems like this my.cnf is not for your database

Comment: starnge. in which way youve restarted your mysql server?

Comment: viewing database with phpmyadmin or which tool? restart then see this http://joxi.ru/52aROo1u5np5A0 on bottom red circle in english will be somthing near "Server started at $datetime"

Comment: I am using Sqlyog for viewing database.Stop and Start is not problem.problem. Tht's working fine

Comment: not ok is that after your reboot max_allowed_packet is still 1024. so there only 2 reasons: 1 server reads another my.cnf. 2 server not rebooted. thats all

Comment: i have only one my.cnf file in /etc/mysql/my.cnf.Restarting server taking 32M then after only it automatically reduced to 1024